# How to grant access to certain folders in my Google Drive to users logging in via Google Drive API

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-javascript-client

I was playing with Java Script Google Drive API and was able to successfully fetch my google drive content via API.

Now lets say i have certain files in certain folders and on logging in to my App by other users, they can access these files in my drive. Is this possible with current Google Drive API where users can log-in to my APP and access my files in my google drive.

Here is the code for fetching files from google drive:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Drive API Quickstart</title>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Drive API Quickstart</p>

    <!--Add buttons to initiate auth sequence and sign out-->
    <button id="authorize-button" style="display: none;">Authorize</button>
    <button id="signout-button" style="display: none;">Sign Out</button>

    <pre id="content"></pre>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      // Client ID and API key from the Developer Console
      var CLIENT_ID = 'CLIENT_ID_GOES_HERE';

      // Array of API discovery doc URLs for APIs used by the quickstart
      var DISCOVERY_DOCS = ["https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/drive/v3/rest"];

      // Authorization scopes required by the API; multiple scopes can be
      // included, separated by spaces.
      var SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly';

      var authorizeButton = document.getElementById('authorize-button');
      var signoutButton = document.getElementById('signout-button');

      /**
       *  On load, called to load the auth2 library and API client library.
       */
      function handleClientLoad() {
        gapi.load('client:auth2', initClient);
      }

      /**
       *  Initializes the API client library and sets up sign-in state
       *  listeners.
       */
      function initClient() {
        gapi.client.init({
          discoveryDocs: DISCOVERY_DOCS,
          clientId: CLIENT_ID,
          scope: SCOPES
        }).then(function () {
          // Listen for sign-in state changes.
          gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.listen(updateSigninStatus);

          // Handle the initial sign-in state.
          updateSigninStatus(gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.get());
          authorizeButton.onclick = handleAuthClick;
          signoutButton.onclick = handleSignoutClick;
        });
      }

      /**
       *  Called when the signed in status changes, to update the UI
       *  appropriately. After a sign-in, the API is called.
       */
      function updateSigninStatus(isSignedIn) {
        if (isSignedIn) {
          authorizeButton.style.display = 'none';
          signoutButton.style.display = 'block';
          listFiles();
        } else {
          authorizeButton.style.display = 'block';
          signoutButton.style.display = 'none';
        }
      }

      /**
       *  Sign in the user upon button click.
       */
      function handleAuthClick(event) {
        gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signIn();
      }

      /**
       *  Sign out the user upon button click.
       */
      function handleSignoutClick(event) {
      alert('out');
      auth2.disconnect();
        gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signOut();
      }

      /**
       * Append a pre element to the body containing the given message
       * as its text node. Used to display the results of the API call.
       *
       * @param {string} message Text to be placed in pre element.
       */
      function appendPre(message) {
        var pre = document.getElementById('content');
        var textContent = document.createTextNode(message + '\n');
        pre.appendChild(textContent);
      }

      /**
       * Print files.
       */
      function listFiles() {
        gapi.client.drive.files.list({
          'pageSize': 10,
          'fields': "nextPageToken, files(id, name)"
        }).then(function(response) {
          appendPre('Files:');
          var files = response.result.files;
          if (files && files.length > 0) {
            for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
              var file = files[i];
              appendPre(file.name + ' (' + file.id + ')');
            }
          } else {
            appendPre('No files found.');
          }
        });
      }

    </script>

    <script async defer src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"
      onload="this.onload=function(){};handleClientLoad()"
      onreadystatechange="if (this.readyState === 'complete') this.onload()">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: anyone having any experience with this API?

Answer (score 0):

Based from this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/about-auth), when your application needs access to user data, it asks Google for a particular [scope](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/about-auth#what_scope_or_scopes_does_my_app_need) of access.

> The scope `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file` strikes this balance in a practical way. Presumably, users only open or create a file with an app that they trust, for reasons they understand.

As stated [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-sharing), access to files & folders is determined by an access control list (ACL). An ACL is a list of permissions that determine whether or not users can perform actions on a file such as read or write. You may check the [permissions guide](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/about-permissions) for additional details about permissions and roles.